# NSURLConnection crashes after all the data is uploaded and before connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an uploader class (`mediaUploader`) which gets a `NSData` and uploads it to a particular server. This class is not singleton and can be instantiated (Although a singleton QueueManager class is implemented to dispatch each upload request to an object of `mediaUploader` ).
The problem is this implementation has been working for over a month now, but suddenly when I upload 2 files in a row the first one is uploaded with no problems and the `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method of `NSURLConnection` is called for it. But the second one is uploaded to 100% (I know because I'm tracing the progress of uploading in the `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`) but does not go to `connectionDidFinish` method nor the `connectionDidFail`. 
After that `connection:didReceiveResponse:` and `connection:didReceiveData:` are also called (Normal transition for a normal upload also does this) but after these two usually the `didFinishLoading` method should be called which is not and my app crashes.
My stack trace is as follows:

```
#0  0x00000000 in 0x00000000 ()
#1  0x3186ffc2 in __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke ()
#2  0x3186ff06 in -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] ()
#3  0x3186fe20 in -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] ()
#4  0x30b97106 in ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke ()
#5  0x30b95d16 in ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 ()
#6  0x30e64980 in CFArrayApplyFunction ()
#7  0x30b2d7fa in RunloopBlockContext::perform() ()
#8  0x30b2d6b8 in MultiplexerSource::perform() ()
#9  0x30b2d54c in MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) ()
#10 0x30efc25a in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x30efb72a in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#12 0x30ef9f1e in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x30e64f4e in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x30e64d32 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x35d69662 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x337b016c in UIApplicationMain ()
#17 0x00263fc8 in main at /Users/mepla/Projects/BApp-ios/BApp/main.m:15
```

I also add the initialization of my connection in case there is a problem there:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    request.URL = requestURL;

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSUInteger timeinterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%d", timeinterval];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uuid\"\r\n\r\n%@", uuid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n%@", username] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"host\"\r\n\r\n%@", XMPPDomain] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", _mediaIdentifier] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:_uploadData]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:NSURLConnectionTimeout];


    _rawResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                   initWithRequest:request
                   delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [_connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [_connection start];
```

So, any help regarding this problem is much appreciated. Please keep in mind that this code was working fine for a long time and out of nowhere I'm getting this today. :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In addition, I also have a `mediaDownloader` class which works in exactly the same way and there is no problems with that. It works with as many download request as I pass to it.

Comment: try this: the Microsoft method: Product -> Clean. Quit XCode. Quit iOS Simulator. Detach all connected iOS-devices. Open XCode again, etc.

Comment: this has worked more than once for me! XCode is still a rather buggy dev-environment!

Comment: @Michael But the crash hasn't anything to do with Xcode!

Comment: so... you obviously haven't had this problem before, right?

Comment: @Melpa I would explicitly set a Content-Type header for the file. For multipart form data parts, the default content type (if not specified) equals `text/plain`. For a file with unknown content type you should specify `application/octet-stream`, otherwise the well known MIME type.

Comment: 1. You've shared the stack trace, but what is the exception code/address? What precisely was the crash? 2. The only thing that leaps to mind is if the delegate object is getting deallocated prematurely. I'd suggest implementing `dealloc` method in your delegate object, so you can see if this is the case.

Comment: @Rob I thought about a prematurely deallocated delegate as well, however, `NSURLConnection` _retains_ the delegate for the duration of the connection. :/  However, another cause of the issue would be if the delegate has been explicitly set to nil (accidentally of course).

Comment: did you do any upgrade between the working code and the non-working code? e.g. a upgrade from iOS 6 to iOS 7 or a upgrade from XCode 5.0 to XCode 5.1, or a upgrade from OSX 10.8 to OSX 10.9?

Comment: the real question is: why does an anonymous block inside `-_withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:` call the NULL-function?

Comment: @Michael: Yes i have actually upgraded Xcode to 5.1 in this period. Actually i tried your first method: I closed everything up and removed all devices and my problem was solved. But before that I changed something in my UploadQueueHandler, so I dont really know which one actually solved the problem, but make your suggestion an answer and I'll try to reproduce the situation if it really works I'd mark that as correct answer. Anyways thank you and everybody who took the time to help ;)

Comment: @Rob: Thank you man but I checked and the delegate doesn't seem to be deallocated prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

After a very close look at these lines:

```
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",
    _mediaIdentifier] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

shouldn't it be

```
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",
    _mediaIdentifier] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

?

Note: you may use a diff tool to make it obvious ;)

However, as already suggested in my comment, I would add a Content-Type header:

```
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",
    _mediaIdentifier] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: XXX/xxx\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: this doesn't explain the crash, though

Comment: It *may* be related to the crash IFF `NSURLConnection` will parse a multipart form-data message. However, I doubt it actually will. So, there's little chance the crash will disappear. Nonetheless, it's a bug - and will confuse the server and corrupt the received content.

Comment: Well because this exact code has been working smoothly for a period of time and I didnt change it I doubt that the Content-Disposition string would be the problem. On the other hand my server responds to unknown MIME_types it receives, so if the I'm sending unknown data I'd get back the server response immediately. Thank you very much for taking the time to comment here, Im gonna try some of the things you said but the problems appears to be solved. Ty ;)